# How to draw the knot 2, -32, 41?

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

Hej,

I have the following exercise:

*Draw the tangle 2, -32, 41 and the corresponding knots obtained by connecting the NW string to the NE string and the SW string to the SE string.* (From C. C. Adams's book *The Knot Book*).

I am not sure if I understood the notations correctly, so can someone confirms if I drew the knot correctly or if not, let me know what I understood wrong?

[image: Knots_2,-31,41?]

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Comment: Can you upload a picture of what you drew?  It will be easier if you show us what you did.

Comment: There already is a picture attached @N.Owad Aren't you able to see it?

Comment: I can now.  Don't know why that I couldn't before.